# Manadev SEO Layered Navigation Plus issue in magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7

I am using SEO Layered Navigation Plus < http://www.manadev.com/seo-layered-navigation-plus > in Magento 1.7. Few days age, I have put some demo products and it was working fine but when my site goes to live server and I have deleted all the products then it is not working.

Suppose, I have a attribute "Color" with two option White, block etc. Now I click on white then the products are not filtering but the url is changing. Now the strange thing is - After that, if I am refreshing the page then it will redirect to 404 error page.

Please, help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the following:

- Make sure you unsecure, secure base URL is pointing correctly to your live website and try to flush your Magento cache storage.
- Are you using the latest version of the extension ?, maybe you should check for any new updates, the last version was 3.10.